# How to add WPF to Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: wpf

I have downloaded and installed Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone. Is there a way to be able to code WPF apps for Windows too? Can I *upgrade* Visual Studio, because at the moment I can only create windows phone apps. Haven't found anything on the web.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get [Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop) (or a paid SKU) to develop WPF applications.

Comment: Will I have 2 separate Visual Studios or will they be together?

Comment: Last question, thanks for your help! Is there a way (like in Visual Studio 2010) to have all the development environments together? Windows Phone and Desktop apps in one install?

Comment: @CemYesil Use a non-express version.  The paid SKUs (like Pro) allow you to do everything in one install.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop

This version is for Desktop apps.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install "Express for Windows Phone"? Perhaps try "Express for Windows Desktop"?

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop

(must admit I've not tried express in a while, but it looks like they are different installers. I've always found Visual Studio works well side-by-side with different versions these days, so I imagine you can install both.)